# How to save $_GET data to a file PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to save all key values from the `GET` parameters, but its not writing anything to the file.

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
   $contents = $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";
   echo($contents);
   file_put_contents("./test.log", $contents, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: Any error. Also what is the output of `var_dump ($_GET);`?

Comment: Don't put your file write inside the loop, it's very inefficient. Build your string and then write it.

Comment: No errors. I know the script is receiving the $_GET data bc I echoed it.

Comment: it should still write something to the file. @miken32

Comment: Yes it should, that's not the answer to the problem. Just a suggestion for something you should be doing. Probably it's a file permission problem. Do a check before you try writing: http://php.net/is_writable

Comment: @miken32 file permissions are 777

Comment: That's a bad idea. It also doesn't mean the file is writable; it depends on the directories above it as well. There could also be other issues such as AppArmor or SELinux getting in the way.

Comment: I dont have any php security installed, and yeah I know 777 isn't good lol

Comment: Try writing to `/tmp` and see what happens. That shouldn't present any permissions problems.

Comment: try to open file with php, to confirm path file first

Comment: If this was resolved as a result of a problem with your file, you should self-answer or just delete the question. Only accept an answer if it would be helpful for other users to answer a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `file_put_contents()` inside loop. Put it outside:-

```
$contents='';
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $contents .= $key . " => " . $value . "\n"; // or use `"\r\n"`            
}
file_put_contents("./test.log", $contents, FILE_APPEND);
```

*Note:- Check that file have write permission `(644)` + folder in which this file lies have the permission too `(777)` and path of the file is correct.*

***Below are the screen-shots of working code at my local end:-*** http://prntscr.com/e98o04  And http://prntscr.com/e98oco

Comment: @isethi this code is working completely fine at my local end. I had checked it twice  (with .txt and with .log)

Comment: @Anant thanks I got it to work. something was wrong with my file

Comment: @isethi  glad to help you .  :):):)

Answer (score 2):

print_r will give you the same output you are trying to build, and you can solve this using just one line.

```
file_put_contents("./test.log", print_r($_GET, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

AS i seen the save data in file is in every iteration an only at iteration current position:

```
$contents='';
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $contents.= $key . " => " . $value . "<br>";            
}
file_put_contents("./test.log", $contents, FILE_APPEND);
```

Same path of php code?, not needed "./", could you try to open file, before and put here if there is no error.

Comment: have you see if file exists?, got permissions, could you can put the error if is?, any way as i have didnt put that works, only tells you that put outside iteration file_put_contents

Comment: yep permissions are 777 for the file. and the apache access log shows receiving the get request